# How to remove an element after animation in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a PHP version toastmessage from akquinet's jQuery toastmessage plugin: [jquery-toastmessage-plugin](http://akquinet.github.io/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/). Everything works fine so far here.
The plugin provides an animation when removing the toastmessage. I tried to extract the function of removing the toastmessage after the animation with this code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Peter92/05n2swh4/5/)

```
function remove(el){
    el.animate({opacity:'0'},600,function(){
        el.animate({height:'0'},300,function(){
            el.animate({display:'none'},100,function(){
                el.remove()
            })
        })
    })
}
```

But the element shows up again after the animation. I also tried to put `el.remove()` outside. It does remove the element, though, the animation is totally skipped. hide() or fadeOut() are not reacting when clicked. I don't wanna give the animation, what should I do?

Comment: In the example you're not using jQuery animate, but calling the native [`animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) function on an `Element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you change the element-selector first of all to `.closest()` method as you can then change the structure within your modal without breaking the `this.parentElement.parentElement` which you use at the moment:

```js
<div class="toast-item-close" onclick="remove(this.closest('.toast-item-wrapper'))">X</div>
```

For the animation, you need to add an [onfinish callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/onfinish):

```js
function remove(el){
  const animation = el.animate(
    [
       {height: '0'},
       {opacity: '0'},
    ],
    {
       duration: 500,
    }
  )

  animation.onfinish = () => el.remove()
}
```

Comment: Also recommend using `addEventListener` over the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Glad it helped. Make sure to mark the answer as correct if you are satisfied so its visible on the index that your question is already resolved! Cheers